# ¿Cómo hacer un select tag dependiente con AJAX en Rails?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails

Soy nuevo en Rails. Necesito realizar un lista de selección (`select_tag`) ya que tengo dos modelos: uno de proyectos y otro de Actividades los cuales están relacionando de la siguiente forma: un proyecto tiene muchas actividades.

Lo que requiero es que cuando seleccione un Proyecto dinámicamente me aparezcan en otro `select_tag` las actividades que están relacionas con el dicho proyecto.

Comment: Hola Leonard, bienvenido a SOes. Te sugiero leer [ask] para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas. En vez de agradecer en la misma pregunta puedes votar o aceptar una respuesta que te sea útil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo utilizar el *helper* `collection_select` en lugar de `select_tag`, es más sencillo pues está pensado para generar elementos `select` a partir de modelos.

Lo que buscas es sencillo (rails te facilita mucho el camino) y sólo necesitas de cuatro puntos para lograrlo:

- Generar una acción en el controlador para responder a la solicitud *AJAX*.
- Actualizar tus rutas para poder alcanzar esa acción en el controlador.
- Generar el `script` para realizar la solicitud *AJAX*.
- Generar la vista (`js`) asociada a la nueva acción del controlador.

Ejemplo:

**Modelos**

```
# app/models/project.rb

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  # atributos/columnas: id, name
  has_many :activities
end
```

```
# app/models/activity.rb

class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  # atributos/columnas: id, name, project_id
  belongs_to :project
end
```

**Controlador**

```
# controllers/activities_controller.rb

class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController   
  def new
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  # otras acciones

  def options
    @activities = Activity.where(project_id: params[:project_id])
  end
end
```

La acción puedes agregarla en cualquier controlador (si deseas seguir fiel a *REST*), en el ejemplo la puse en el mismo controlador de `ActivitiesController` para mantenerlo simple.

También podrías obtener las actividades con:

```
@activities = Project.find(params[:project_id]).activities
```

Y obtendrías el mismo resultado, sin embargo no decidí utilizar esta opción ya que genera dos consultas a la BD (la que puse en el ejemplo solo genera una).

**Rutas**

```
# config/routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :activities
  post 'activities/options', as: 'activities_options'
  # otras rutas
end
```

Además de las rutas *REST* generadas con `resources`, agregamos la nueva ruta para `options`, la cual debe ser `post`.

**Vistas**

```
<!-- app/views/new.html.erb -->

<div id="projects">
  <%= collection_select(:project, :name, @projects, :id, :name, prompt: "Seleciona proyecto") %>
</div>
<div id="activities"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#project_name').on('change', function() {
      $.ajax({
        url:  "<%= activities_options_path %>",
        type: "POST",
        data: { project_id: $(this).val() }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

`collection_select` utiliza la variable `@projects` para generar las opciones; en este caso mostrará todos los proyectos, donde el `id` será el valor y `name` será el text que se muestre.

El `script` llama la nueva ruta generada enviando el (a través de *POST*) el `project_id`, con el cual se obtienen las actividades que deseas mostrar en el nuevo `select`.

El `div` con `id="activities"` está simplemente reservando el espacio donde se ubicará el `select` de actividades una vez que sea generado.

```
/* app/views/options.js.erb */

var html = "<%= j(collection_select(:activity, :name, @activities, :id, :name)) %>";
$('#activities').html(html);
```

Al ser `js.erb` utilizas únicamente *JavaScript*/*jQuery* (la `j` en `j(collection.select(...)` se utiliza para poder generar html que sea aceptado por javascript) con el cual indicamos que genera un nuevo `select` con las actividades del proyecto (i.e. `@activities`) y que este sea agregado dentro del `div` con `id="activities"`.

Comment: ! Al comienzo empecé a utilizar collection pero debido a que no lograba intente hacerlo con select_tag probaré! Gracias! Saludos.

Comment: @LeonardJ.ÁvilaS. Lo importante del `collection_select` es entender los argumentos: objeto del modelo (`:project`), método/columna (`:name`), opciones (`@projects`), valor para las opciones (`:id`) y texto para las opciones (`:name`).

Comment: Saludos Gerry! Hice un proyecto nuevo en (rails) para probar lo que me indicaste, pero me ocurre algo no se me renderiza el colletion de actividades pareciera que no esta tomado el new.js.erb primera vez que uso (file.js.erb) :( No se si falta colocar algo en el controlador para responder.

Comment: @LeonardJ.ÁvilaS. Ohh, cometí un error: la vista se debe llamar igual que la acción; cambia el nombre de `new.js.erb` a `options.js.erb` (que es la acción que responde al _AJAX_). He actualizado mi respuesta para reflejar el cambio.

Comment: Listo! Lo cambie el nombre y nada no se muestra el colletion. Qué dices si subo el proyecto a Git para que lo puedas ver. :(((

Comment: @LeonardJ.ÁvilaS. Perfecto, súbelo y así podré ver el código completo.

Comment: Ok, ya lo haré.

Comment: Gerry! Listo, aquí esta el repo https://github.com/LeonardJAvi/test-select-rails

Comment: Ok. Ya reviso. :)

Comment: @LeonardJ.ÁvilaS. También te envié un _pull request_ para que puedas verlo directamente en tu repositorio.

Comment: Sí, ya lo ví. Ya probé que bien! Esta cool, infinitas gracias! Sí puede enviame tú correo para que platicar sobre tecnologías de desarrollo. 0/

Comment: @LeonardJ.ÁvilaS. Súper! Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada (dando clic a la paloma del lado izquierdo). Puedes contactarme en ge_graham@yahoo.com. Suerte!

Comment: Ok, gracias! Saludos.

Comment: Hola Gerry! Estás por aquí?