# Como pasar collection_select a formato de la gema simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Buenas comunidad, tengo un problema con la gema de simple form, ya que requiero pasar un colletion_select a formato simple form, al hacerlo de da un error de método. Agradezco su ayuda. Gracias!

Comment: Hole Leonard, ¿podrías [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/96136/edit) tu pregunta y agregar el código que estás utilizando actualmente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomando el ejemplo de tu [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95288/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-un-select-tag-dependiente-con-ajax-en-rails):

```
<%= collection_select(:project, :name, @projects, :id, :name, prompt: "Seleciona proyecto") %>
```

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
<%= simple_form_for @object do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :project, collection: @projects, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, label: "Proyecto", include_blank: true %>
   <!-- Otros inputs -->
<% end %>
```

Donde `@object` se refiere al objeto que deseas crear en la forma.

Comment: Ok, lo probaré. Gracias!

Comment: Excelente. Muchas gracias!