# ¿como hacer una selección anidada en la misma vista en RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Necesito cargar la dirección de una persona en este orden: estado, municipio y parroquia para esto tengo tres tablas en db/schema.rb

```
create_table "estados", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "nombre", limit: 100, null: false
end

create_table "municipios", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "nombre", limit: 100, null: false
  t.bigint "estado_id", null: false
end

create_table "parroquias", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "nombre"
  t.bigint "municipio_id"
end
```

Mediante un menú desplegable quiero que al seleccionar un estado, en la siguiente selección me salgan los municipios de ese estado, al seleccionar el municipio, en la siguiente selección me salgan las parroquias de ese estado, solo tengo el código se selección para el estado, pero no sé como enlazarlos para que me salgan los municipios del estado seleccionado en la misma vista.

Este es el código que tengo en el helper:

```
def estados_for_select
  Estado.all.collect { |m| [m.nombre, m.id] }
end
```

Y el código que tengo en la vista.

```
<%= f.select :estado_id, estados_for_select, { :prompt => 'Desconocido'}, { :class => "mostrar form-control", :style => "width: 155px;"} %>
```

¿Alguna idea que me oriente como puedo obtener los municipios de ese estado y al seleccionar el municipio me salgan las parroquias de ese estado?

Comment: Creo que no hay una forma simple con rails puro que puedas hacer esto. Una sería que cargues todos los estados, municipios y parroquias y que vayas mostrando/ocultando a través de javascript la que necesites. La otra es que hagas llamadas asíncronas al servidor para traer la info de municipios/parroquias dependiendo del estado/municipio elegido y cargarlas en tu `<select>` a través de js. Cuál elegir... todo depende de lo que requieras, la 1ra carga más info en un inicio, la 2da realiza más requests al servidor.

Comment: Si es mucha info a cargar (demasiados estados, municipios y parroquias) quizás la 2da sea una buena idea, si vas a tener muchos usuarios cargando una y otra vez la misma información, llenándote el servidor a puros requests para traer siempre la misma info, podrías considerar la primera opción (y cachear, pero eso ya es otra historia)

Comment: Puedes utilizar AJAX para solicitar al servidor las opciones correspondientes en cada `select`; puedes ver un ejemplo [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95288/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-un-select-tag-dependiente-con-ajax-en-rails/95320#95320).

Comment: Excelente mi pana Gerry, funciona tu ejemplo, ahora me toca desarrollarlo hasta la parroquia!