# ¿Cómo puedo usar el helper collection_select dos veces en rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Necesito cargar la dirección de una persona en este orden: estado, municipio y parroquia para esto tengo tres tablas en db/schema.rb

```
create_table "estados", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "nombre", limit: 100, null: false
end

create_table "municipios", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "nombre", limit: 100, null: false
  t.bigint "estado_id", null: false
end

create_table "parroquias", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "nombre"
  t.bigint "municipio_id"
end
```

Gracias a esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95288/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-un-select-tag-dependiente-con-ajax-en-rails/95320#95320), pude desarrollar el código para que el estado me traiga los municipios de ese estado, pero no logro que el municipio me traiga las parroquias de ese municipio, les dejo mi código:

**Modelos:**

estado.rb

```
class Estado < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :municipios
end
```

municipio.rb

```
class Municipio < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :estado
  has_many :parroquias
end
```

parroquia.rb

```
class Parroquia < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :municipio
end
```

**En el controlador tengo:**

```
  def municipios
    @municipios = Municipio.where(estado_id: params[:estado_id])
  end

  def parroquias
    @parroquias = Parroquia.where(municipio_id: params[:municipio_id])
  end
```

**En las rutas tengo:**

```
  post 'contactos/municipios', as: 'municipios_opcion'
  post 'contactos/parroquias', as: 'parroquias_opcion'
```

**En las vistas tengo:**

```
<div id="estados">
  <%= collection_select(:estado, :nombre, @estados, :id, :nombre, prompt: "Selecciona un estado") %>
</div>
<div id="municipios"></div>
<div id="parroquias"></div>
. . . 
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#estado_nombre').on('change', function() {
      $.ajax({
        url:  "<%= municipios_opcion_path %>",
        type: "POST",
        data: { estado_id: $(this).val() }
      });
    });
  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#municipio_nombre').on('change', function() {
      $.ajax({
        url:  "<%= parroquias_opcion_path %>",
        type: "POST",
        data: { municipio_id: $(this).val() }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

**/* app/views/municipios.js.erb */**

```
var html = "<%= j(collection_select(:municipio, :nombre, @municipios, :id, :nombre)) %>";
$('#municipios').html(html);
```

**/* app/views/parroquias.js.erb */**

```
var html = "<%= j(collection_select(:parroquia, :nombre, @parroquias, :id, :nombre)) %>";
$('#parroquias').html(html)
```

¿alguna idea que me falta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tu error está en que llamas a `$('#municipio_nombre').on('change')` antes de que siquiera esté creado en el dom el elemento `municipio_nombre`. Prueba con:

```
var html = "<%= j(collection_select(:municipio, :nombre, @municipios, :id, :nombre)) %>";
$('#municipios').html(html);
$('#municipio_nombre').on('change', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url:  "<%= parroquias_opcion_path %>",
    type: "POST",
    data: { municipio_id: $(this).val() }
  });
});
```

Y un detalle, pero como convención los requests de tipo POST se realizan cuando vas a crear o modificar algo por el lado del servidor. Si para este caso en que solo estás trayendo información desde el server, lo más adecuando es que configures tu `config/routes.rb` con peticiones de tipo GET.

Comment: Funciona, pero cuando hay un solo municipio o es el primero de la lista  no me trae las parroquias, probé con el get pero me da un error de: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Contacto with 'id'=municipios:
  app/controllers/contactos_controller.rb:178:in `set_contacto'

Comment: @rrg1459 claro, si cambias a get, también tienes que cambiar la forma en que mandas los parámetros desde el request ajax. Respecto a que no funciona con el primero, muestra información del error o no podré saber que pasa. ¿qué información manda al realizar el request? ¿que te retorna? ¿está arrojando algún error la consola del navegador? ¿los ids están correctos dentro de los options del select?

Comment: Ya resolví poniendo un , prompt: "Selecciona un municipio")) %>";, de esa forma lo obligo a hacer una transacción, te agradezco la paciencia que me tienes y al amigo Gerry, ya que estoy aprendiendo cada vez mas esto de la programación, voy a ver lo del get y como cambiar los parametros.