# Obteniendo datos json desde Rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails

Estoy intentando poder obtener datos json desde Rails, automaticamente obtengo un archivo llamado _item.json.jbuilder, y estoy intentando extraer esos datos al log o en su defecto a la vista, sin embargo a modo de prueba al log del navegador, y lo intento haciendolo de la siguiente manera, sin embargo no consigo realizarlo:

```
function traer(){
  fetch('item.json.jbuilder')
    .then( res => res.json ())
    .then( datos => {
      console.log(datos)
    } )
}
```

Los datos del json serian:

```
json.extract! item, :id, :code, :name, :item_type_id, :created_at, :updated_at
json.url item_url(item, format: :json)
```

Agradezco puedan ayudarme

**Actualización**

```
function traer(){
  fetch('../items.json')
    .then( res => res.json ())
    .then( datos => {
      console.log(datos)
    } )
}

<%= output_item.collection_select :item_id, Item.all, :id, :name, { :include_blank => "Seleccionar" } %>
```

Comment: ¿y has visto que te retorna en la consola de navegador, en la sección de redes? en la sección de XHR puedes revisar el response.

Comment: Si claro, olvide mencionar que me produce este error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Eso es porque no viene un json válido como respuesta, en la sección de redes deberías poder ver la respuesta. Si no, prueba a cambiar `res.json ()` por `console.log(res)` para ver que viene.

Comment: Saludos Alter, gracias por contestar, de momento he logrado solucionarlo, retrocediendo un directorio, ¿De que forma Alter puedo filtrar ese json y que me lo liste en el select? He agregado el codigo corredigo mas el select en la actualizacion del post

Comment: Creo que [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/95320/213) te puede dar ideas de como hacer lo que requieres. Saludos

Comment: Te agradezco Alter!