# Cargar datos de un select que depende de otro select Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

Tengo la tabla llamada Áreas, tiene 2 columnas, "nombre" y "Parent_id" y se llena de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, hay un área principal y una secundaria, la secundaria tendrá un padre que será el área principal (parent_id).

Intento hacer un Select donde este primero solo tiene las áreas principales, y luego, dependiendo del área principal que se elija, en otro Select se actualizan a las áreas secundarias que pertenecen a la principal.

```
 <div class="grid_6">
  <%= f.label "Main Area" %><br>
  <%= f.select :area_id, Area.select_minimal.map{|u| [u.name, u.id]}, {:include_blank => "Select Main Area"}, {:class => "style-select_medium"}  %>
</div>
<div class="grid_6">
  <%= f.label :"Secondary Area" %><br>
  <%= f.select :second_area_id, Area.select_minimal.map{|u| [u.name, u.id]}, {:include_blank => "Select Second Area"}, {:class => "style-select_medium"}  %>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo hacer un select tag dependiente con AJAX en Rails?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95288/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-un-select-tag-dependiente-con-ajax-en-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo haría es escuchar los cambios del primer select con javascript usando (onchange) y en cuanto cambie hacer una petición AJAX para cargar los datos de el segundo select.