# Llenar select dependiente en Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

Adentrándome en el maravilloso mundo Ruby on Rails me encuentro con un pequeño problema que no consigo resolver.

A ver si me podéis echar una mano.

El clásico Provincias - Localidades para un form de usuario

Los modelos:
User - Provincium - Localidad

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :localidad
  belongs_to:provincium
end

class Provincium < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :localidads
  has_many :users
end

class Localidad < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :provincium, optional: true
  has_many :users
end
```

Controlador de User

```
  def select_provincia
    @localidades = Localidad.where( provincia_id: params[:idProvincia] )
    respond_to do |l|
      l.json {render json: @localidades}
    end
  end
```

_form (con simple_form)

```
<%= f.association :provincium, label: "Provincias", label_method: :nombre, value_method: :id, input_html: {id:"provincias"} %>
  <%= f.input :localidad, collection: @localidades , label_method: :nombre, value_method: :id %>
```

select_provincia.js

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $( "#provincias" ).change(function() {
    var idProvincia = Number( $( "#provincias" ).val() );
    console.log(idProvincia);
    $.ajax({
      url: "/users/new/select_provincia",
      type: "get",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {idProvincia: idProvincia},
      success: function (data){},
      error: function (data){}
    });
  });
});
```

Ruta

```
      get "select_provincia", on: :new
  end
```

El caso es que me hace la petición de manera correcta y en el inspector del navegador me devuelve el JSON perfecto.

Pero la vista no me lo muestra. De hecho el select no aparece como tal, sino como input de texto.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Mientras en `success: function (data){}` no hagas nada con el json resultante, no hay forma que salga en el select, ahí es donde deberías recorrer el json y generar options para tu select. Otra forma sería seguir los pasos finales [de esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/95320/213), de tal forma que generes un template html como respuesta en vez de un json. Personalmente creo que es más limpio esta última forma en vez de generar el html a través de js, pero ve tú ahí que te sale más simple de hacer.

Comment: Gracias! Por ahora he dejado esta funcionalidad a un lado. En cuanto vuelva por ella comentaré.