# ¿Como hacer un dropdown dependiente en rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dropdown

Soy nuevo en rails y lo que he aprendido hasta el momento no me alcanza para realizar la siguiente tarea.

Necesito realizar un filtro de una búsqueda por medio de dropdown's, la idea es que en un dropdown muestre las zones, si eligen x zone muestre en otro dropdown los centers que pertenecen a esa zone.

Les comparto lo que hasta el momento he implementado:

**En los modelos están estas relaciones**

```rb
# Modelo Points
class Point < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :center
  belongs_to :zone
end

# Modelo Zones
class Zone < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :centers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :points
end

# Modelo Centers
class Center < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :point, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :zone
end
```

**en el controlador de points en el metodo index**

```rb
def index
    @p = Point.all
    # Sentencia para realizar la busqueda por centro de costo
    @p = @p.where('center_id = ?', params[:center_id]) if params[:center_id].present?
    # Sentencia para realizar la busqueda por zonas
    @p = @p.where('zone_id = ?', params[:zone_id]) if params[:zone_id].present?
end
```

**En la vista points** Esta el formulario el cual realiza la búsqueda ya sea por zonas, center o zonas y centers

```rb
<%= form_tag points_path, method: :get do %>
      <div class="form-group">
           <%= select_tag :zone_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Zone.all, "id", "nombre", params[:zone_id]), prompt: "Zonas", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
           <%= select_tag :center_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Center.all, "id", "nombre", params[:center_id]), prompt: "Centros de Costo", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <%= submit_tag "Buscar", name: nil, class: "btn btn-danger btn-md" %>
<% end %>
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo hacer un select tag dependiente con AJAX en Rails?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/95320/213)

Comment: He leído y he tratado de entender el código pero aun no logro cumplir

Comment: ¿Hasta dónse has llegado?, ¿puedes mostrar tu implementación para ver dónde te está dando problemas?

Comment: Hola @Gerry, acabo de editar la pregunta. Puedes echarle una mirada.