# Quiero un formulario en RoR donde se coloca un departamento las ciudades se cambien es decir si coloco amazonas se coloquen las ciudades de este

Tags: formularios, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<%= form_for(@usuario) do |f| %>
    
    <% if @usuario.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation" >
            <h2><%=pluralize(@usuario.errors.count, "error") %></h2>
            <ul>
                <% @usuario.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :nombre%><br>
        <%= f.text_field :nombre%>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :apellido%><br>
        <%= f.text_field :apellido%>
    </div>
    
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :genero%><br>
        <%= f.select :genero, ["Seleccione uno","H","M","Otro","Prefiero no decirlo"],selected:"Seleccione uno" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :tipo_de_identificacion%><br>
        <%= f.select :tipo_de_identificacion, ["Seleccione uno","T.I","C.C","C.E"],selected:"Seleccione uno" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :numero_de_identifacion%><br>
        <%= f.text_field :numero_de_identifacion%>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email%><br>
        <%= f.text_field :email%>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :password%>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmacion" %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :password_confirmation%>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :fecha_de_nacimiento%><br>
        <%= f.date_field :fecha_de_nacimiento%>
    </div>
    
    <div class="field">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Departamento</td>
                <td>Ciudad o Municipio</td>
                <td>Barrio</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%= f.select :departamento, ["","Amazonas","Antioquia","Arauca","Atlántico","Bogotá","Bolívar","Boyacá","Caldas","Caquetá","Casanare","Cauca","Cesar","Chocó","Córdoba","Cundinamarca","Guainía","Guaviare","Huila","La Guajira","Magdalena","Meta","Nariño","Norte de Santander","Putumayo","Quindío","Risaralda","San Andrés y Providencia","Santander","Sucre","Tolima","Valle del Cauca","Vaupés","Vichada"],selected:"" %></td>
#aqui trate de colocar un if para ver si se actualizaban pero se cambia                
<% if :departamento == "Amazonas"%>
                    <td><%= f.select :ciudad, ["","Amazonas1","Antioquia","Arauca","Atlántico"],selected:"" %></td>
                <% elsif :departamento == "Antioquia"%>
                    <td><%= f.select :ciudad, ["","Amazonas2","Antioquia","Arauca","Atlántico"],selected:"" %></td>
                <% end %>
                <td><%= f.text_field :barrio %></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <%= f.label :direccion %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :direccion%>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :codigo_postal%><br>
        <%= f.text_field :codigo_postal%>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit 'Guardar'%>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! podras describir mejor el problema que tenes con tu codigo? asi como esta, es dificil saber cual es tu problema...

Comment: No explicaste del todo tu problema, pero "adivinando" creo que deberías revisar [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/95320/213).

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo hacer un select tag dependiente con AJAX en Rails?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95288/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-un-select-tag-dependiente-con-ajax-en-rails)