# ¿ Cómo hacer que un form.select sea dependiente de los datos de otro en ruby on rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Actualmente me encuentro trabajando en un sistema de inventarios en ruby on rails 7 y tengo 4 modelos relacionados de la siguiente manera:

models/center.rb

```
class Center < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :destination, dependent: :destroy
end
```

models/destination.rb

```
class Destination < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :center
    validates :description, :center_id, presence: true
    has_many :actives, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :ubications, dependent: :destroy
end
```

models/ubications.rb

```
class Ubication < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :actives, dependent: :destroy
    validates :id, presence: true
    belongs_to :destination
end
```

models/active.rb

```
class Active < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :destination
    belongs_to :ubication
    validates :destination_id, presence: true
    validates :ubication_id, presence: true

end
```

Mi actives_controller.rb tiene lo siguiente:

```
class ActivesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource


  def import1
    file = params[:file]
    return redirect_to actives_path, notice: 'Sólo se admite formato de separación de comas (.CSV)' unless file.content_type == 'text/csv'

    CsvImportActivesService.new.call(file)

    redirect_to actives_path, notice: 'ACTIVOS IMPORTADOS EXITOSAMENTE'
  end
  def import2
    file = params[:file]
    return redirect_to actives_path, notice: 'Sólo se admite formato de separación de comas (.CSV)' unless file.content_type == 'text/csv'

    CsvImportActivesService2.new.call(file)

    redirect_to actives_path, notice: 'ACTIVOS IMPORTADOS EXITOSAMENTE'
  end

  # GET /actives or /actives.json
  def index
    @actives = Active.where(status: true)
    if params[:query_text].present?
      @actives = @actives.search_full_text(params[:query_text])
    end
  end

  def index_not_active
    @actives = Active.where(status: false)
    if params[:query_text].present?
      @actives = @actives.search_full_text(params[:query_text])
    end
  end

  # GET /actives/1 or /actives/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /actives/new
  def new
    @actives = Active.new
    @centers=Center.all.order('name ASC')
    @destinations=Destination.all.order('description ASC')
  end

  # GET /actives/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /actives or /actives.json
  def create
    @active = Active.new(active_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @active.save
        format.html { redirect_to actives_path, notice: "el tipo de activo fue creado" }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @active }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @active.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /actives/1 or /actives/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @active.update(active_params)
        format.html { redirect_to actives_path, notice: "el activo fue actualizado" }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @active }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @active.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /actives/1 or /actives/1.json
  def destroy
    @active.update(status: false, user_id: 80000403900)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to actives_url, notice: "El activo fue dado de baja exitosamente." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def active_params
      params.require(:active).permit(:id, :barcode, :serial, :name, :destination_id, :ubication_id, :plate, :user_id, :rankactive_id, :status, :active_type_id)
    end
end
```

y mi vista actual del form_html.erb unicamente con los selects es esta:

```
<%= form_with(model: active) do |form| %>
<div class="mb-3">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-6">Centros de costo:</label>
          <%= form.select :center_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@centers, :id, :name) %>
        </div> 
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-6">Destinos:</label><br>
          <%= form.select :destination_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@destinations, :id, :description) %>
        </div> 
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-6">Ubicación:</label><br>
          <%= form.select :active, options_from_collection_for_select(Ubication.all.order('name ASC'), :id, :name) %>
        </div> 
 <% end %>
```

**Requiero que en el partial _form.html.erb de /views/actives/_form.html.erb, el cual generé en su momento con un scaffold, existan dos selects en el que al seleccionar el center, el select correspondiente a destination solo me muestre los que se encuentren asociados al center seleccionado.**
¿Cómo podría resolver el problema? ¿alguien tiene alguna información que me pueda compartir para poder solventar esto?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo hacer un select tag dependiente con AJAX en Rails?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/95320/213)

Comment: Me funciona el select dependiente, pero en el formulario de active me genera un error de que el destino está quedando en blanco y no se puede crear. Le añadí ademas unas lineas de codigo al actives_controller.rb: `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]`
 porque me mostraba un error de token de autenticidad CRF

Comment: En consola me muestra el siguiente registro  de acciones  [enlace](https://ibb.co/X7FWPbx)

Comment: Ya logré implementar, era cambiar unas lineas del js hacia el modelo al que estaba apuntando porque me estaba creando fuera del modelo active, por eso quedaba en blanco al crearla, al final me quedó algo como esto `var html = "<%= j(collection_select(:active, :destination_id, @destinations, :id, :description)) %>";
$('#destinations').html(html);`, luego me mostro el error en editar, pero fue solo añadirle la instrucción de `@centers=Center.all ` también en el edit y el update. igual en el js en la petición ajax, cambié a esto en la segunda linea `$('#active_center').on('change', function() {`